# Does it make sense to apply batch normalization to a batch size of 1?

Tags: neural-networks, batch-normalization, residual-networks, normalisation

I am interested in your opinion on the topic if you think that it makes sense to use batch normalization layer in a network that is trained with a batch size of 1. This is a special case as part of an experiment. What effects can be expected?

Answer (score 3):

It's not possible to use batch normalization with a batch size of 1. Batch normalization requires you to calculate the variance of activation values in the current batch, and variance is undefined for a sample of size 1.

Comment: Why it is undefined? It is zero.

Comment: The sample variance formula has a denominator of N - 1. When N = 1, N - 1 = 0, and division by 0 is undefined. @adosar